# Recode 2 variables to one in one line

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a DF like:

```
df=data.frame(a=c(0,0,1,1),b=c(0,1,0,1))
```

only it has a long no. of rows. I'd like to create a column depending on simultaneous values of a & b, e.g

```
df
a  b  c
0  0  10
0  1  11
1  0  12
1  1  13
```

I take this can be done with inner joins, using sqldf or maybe dplyr; is there a quicker way, with or without libraries?

Thanks in advance,   p

Comment: Not sure how did you decide what will be the `c` column values.

Comment: Does it matter? That's why it's called recoding, you simply decide the values you want for your project

Comment: yes because df$c <- 10:(10+nrow(df)) fits the answer, but you probably want something different.

Comment: Maybe something like `library(digest) ; df$c <- apply(df, 1, digest)`

Comment: 10..13 are arbitrary values coming from a data dictionary. Use 20..23 if you prefer. The question is mainly about creating a column from another 2, following a rule. I imagine a double join would work, but seems a bit complicated.

Comment: create a data frame with a map between the a/b values, and your intended value of c. Then use merge to join the two. It will give you control to name c whatever you wish

Comment: Do you mean that you have some other table, call it say `dict` with `a`, `b` and some column `value` and you want to look up the matching (a,b) from `df` in `dict` and grab the matching `value` column? It is unclear where your desired output column `c` comes from.

Comment: Thanks Chris and math.coffee, you got the idea and the answer right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you mean is that you have some other data frame (say called `dictionary`) with a `c` column, and you look up the (a, b) in the dictionary and grab the `c` from there??

```
df=data.frame(a=c(0,0,1,1),b=c(0,1,0,1))
dictionary <- df
dictionary$c <- 10:13
dictionary <- dictionary[sample(4), ] # shuffle it just to prove it works
```

In that case you can do

```
merge(df, dictionary, merge=c('a', 'b'), all.x=T)
```

And that will grab the matching `c` column from `dictionary` and plonk it into `df`. The `all.x` will put a `NA` there if there is no matching (a, b) in `dictionary`.

If speed becomes an issue, you might try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)         # convert to data.table
setDT(dictionary) # convert to data.table
# set key
setkey(df,a,b)
setkey(dictionary,a,b)
# merge
dictionary[df] # will be `df` with the `c` column added, `NA` if no match
```

Comment: Thanks US time all, I've found the entries today @9am when back to work. Yes, it is a lookup, and yes, for 2 variables and not only one. Let me test now!

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(newcol = paste0(a, b))
```

Depending on how you want the new column to be labelled.

If you have a vector of desired values, let's call it lookup:

```
lookup <- 10:100
df %>% mutate(newcol = lookup[as.factor(paste0(a, b))])
```

Comment: Sorry but paste0 does not create the specific values 10..13 I'm looking for, does it? Only combines 2 columns?

Comment: how have you decided on these values, just starting at 10 and increasing?

Answer (score 0):

Super cheaty and only applicable to this example but:

`df$c <- 10 + df$b + df$a*2`?

otherwise, look at ?merge

Comment: True, only applicable to this one.....